# T4MVC generated files and a different location

Tags: t4mvc

Is there a setting where I can point my T4MVC generated files.  They all go in the root of my website.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The generated files actually go wherever T4MVC itself is. So if you move the .tt file elsewhere, that should do it.